# How to remove words in a flat file from a column string of words using SSIS

Tags: c#, string, ssis, script-component

I have a simple flat file like this:

**Forbidden Words**

> Word1
>
> Word6
>
> Word3

Then I'm going to remove these words from a column values in a table like this(words are separated using ';'):

**Original Column Values**

> word1;word5;word8;word2;word6
>
> word2;word4;word1;word0;word9
>
> // and so on

I used an OLE DB Source to read the table from SQL and do some conversion and used a script component to remove these words. I can use a Flat file source to read the forbidden words but how to use them in the script component so make a result like this:

**Transformed Column Values**

> ;word5;word8;word2;
>
> word2;word4;;word0;word9
>
> // and so on

[image]

Comment: That's a broad topic.   Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: @TabAlleman I dont know how to pass those words which are readed through the FlatFileSource to the script component

Comment: Store the words in a variable, either an object (recordset) or a delimited string.   There are a number of ways to do this, whichever you prefer:  https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=SSIS+read+flat+file+into+&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssis+read+flat+file+into+variable&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i22i30l4.0.0.0.7223...........0.C5CuxngGoHQ

Comment: @TabAlleman post your idea as an answer so I can mark it as answer if it works and it would be helpful for others encountering similar problems

Answer (score 0):

You can store the words from the flat file in a variable.   It can either be an Object-type variable that holds a recordset, or a delimited string variable.

Either way, you can then pass the variable to your Script Component and use it in the script to remove the forbidden words from your dataflow.